# MySQL profiler which generates the same data as 'show profiles' at run time

Tags: mysql, profiling

So when I run `show profile for query N`, I get a lot of useful information, like how long the query is spending sending data, freeing up resources, etc.

Unfortunately, the `show profile` command only works from the command prompt. This is a problem, because I have some slow running queries which do well when I run them from the command prompt, but don't do so well when run in a live scenario.

Does anyone know how to get the same kind of data you get from `show profile`, but get it at run time from live queries? I've read answers that talk about using the general query log, but this is **not** want I want, as the general log only lists the queries made and not how much they spent in each phase of their querying.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen that you want before. but you can accomplish what you want by yourself. 
Do develop program which monitors slow log and re-run slow query immediately and print `show profile` output.

I have wrote PHP psuedo code, I checked `show profile` also works well in PHP. but how to monitor slow log and parse log content is not tested. below is just psuedo code. It won't work.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "passwd");

monitor_slow_log($conn);

function monitor_slow_log($conn)
{
    $res = mysql_query("set profiling = 1");

    $fp = fopen("/path/to/slow_log", "r");

    while (($str = fgets($fp, 10000)) !== false)
    {
        $query = parse_and_extract_query($str);
        get_profile_result($str);
    }
}

function parse_and_extract_query($str)
{
    // I'm not sure how to parse it.
    // as you know there are more than slow query.
}

function get_profile_result($query)
{
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        // fetch all record
    }
    mysql_free_result($res);

    // print show profile result
    $res = mysql_query("show profile");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        echo $row["Status"]." ===> ".$row['Duration']."\n";
    }

    mysql_free_result($res);

    // print SHOW PROCESSLIST
    mysql_query("show processlist") and print

    // print SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
    mysql_query("show engine innodb status") and print

    // print SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
    mysql_query("show global status") and print

    // print `top` output
    system('top -n 1');
}
```

additionally, not only `show profile` but also some information would be required as follows.

- SHOW PROCESSLIST
- SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
- SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
- `top` output

Comment: Thanks, @jungsu-heo, but I don't just want to rerun the queries and get their profile then; I want to get their profile *at the time they are run*.

Comment: @TolaOdejayi yes. So I suggested polloing Slow log every 1 second and rerun query asap and show profile.